# Issue with yum - error in importing one of the python modules

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, centos

I am trying to install rpm package on CentOS 6 using `yum install` command, but getting folowing error

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   libldap-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.5 (r265:79063, Nov 12 2010, 00:52:45) 
[GCC 4.4.4 20100525 (Red Hat 4.4.4-5)]
```

Please suggest how to solve this. and ask if more info required.

Comment: "Please install a package which provides this module". Did you try what the output told you to do?

Comment: @jordanm isn't installing  kind of difficult if the python program for `yum` itself doesn't run?

Comment: @jordanm There are lots of dependencies I found while installing OpenLdap rpm...!!

Answer (score 2):

Since `yum` itself is not working you should try to reinstall the libldap `.rpm` by downloading the appropriate package and then use:

```
rpm -ivh <rpm_file_name>
```

You might find it on the Centos site, or otherwise Google for "Centos6 libldap rpm". The following might work for you:

```
wget mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64.rpm
```

(this is the 64 bit version, couldn't determine your architecture)

Comment: I got "ERROR 404: Not Found" for wget...

Comment: @KishanSarsechaGajjar try the update link, or search http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/

Comment: Is "openssh-ldap-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64.rpm" correct one for error `Failed dependencies: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.9)(64bit) is needed by openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64` I got while installing openldap rpm...?

Comment: There seems to be multiple files missing, you have to resolve them one by one until `yum` is working again. `rpm` unlike `yum` will not do that download of dependent packages for you. So download `libnss....rpm` and do `rpm -ihv libldap*.rpm libnss*.rpm`

Comment: @Anton, rpm will do the downloading and installing for you (as long as the dependencies are installed). Just give the URL(s) to the package(s) to install.

Comment: You might try getting the missing package(s) from install media. Perhaps something damaged the package, check what `rpm -V <packagename>` tells you.